# Jquery UI position: wrong top offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, position

When using bigger top offset with jquery ui position method, I get wrong results.

It's hard to describe but I've created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hGjMx/1/

As soon as the top offset reaches a certain value, the offset result gets inverted.

Just a snippet of the JSFiddle:

```
$(".element").position({
        my: "left-228 top-" + topOffset,
        at: "left top",
        of: ".baseElement"
    });
```

On my website it's perfectly works in google chrome using the full screen mode. 
On the JSFiddle it sometimes works based on the size of the JSFiddle css window...

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `fitmode`. The jQuery UI position utility has an intelligent collision detection system that will position the element based on its proximity to the edges of its container, so once it gets too close to one edge, it will flip the position (which is why you see the inversion) to try and fit it better

See the `collision` option in the [API docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

Comment: Thanks a million for pointing me out! Note: I also had to use the "within" option. The default for "within" is "window" but I've passed the selector for my wrapping div and everything works fine now!

Comment: nice, glad to help :D